# Does JDBC for Postgres have the equivalent of DirectJoin for Cassandra?

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, jdbc, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

With Cassandra, if I need some specific data, all I need to do is pass the keys on join columns (with DirectJoin enabled). This works very well because is fast. But if I do a join with JDBC, first spark load all data, then get the necessary data. This is slow when I need a small fraction of the data.

For exemple: on the right side I have a dataframe (that I get the data from postgres) with 100kk of data, and other side there are a dataframe with 10kk (from other postgres db).

In this scenario that I need 1/10 of the data from the second dataframe, how can I get specific data that match join columns without load all 10kk of data? (note: I don't pass pass a filter because the data is variable and depends on the first dataframe data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, JDBC source in Spark doesn't support such thing. From the existing Spark sources that I know only Cassandra connector supports this kind of pattern.

In some regard this pattern is supported by Delta Lake in combination with bloom filters (right now only on Databricks, with OSS implementation is in plans) and/or data skipping.  So you can try another approach - implement change data capture on the PostgreSQL side, and stream the changes into Delta Lake table, and then access data in it - your database will be very happy not having an additional load on the database servers :-)

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to make my own DirectJoin with JDBC. Although it is already working, I still need to improve performance a lot. I will keep trying, and if I can get the performance bora, I will upload it to GitHub and post the link here for anyone who wants to use it. I did the implementation you suggested and it worked.

Comment: it's interesting that you started to implement a DirectJoin - it may not be very complex, but the main problem is maintenance - it requires plugging into the internals of Spark using the internal Spark APIs, and they are changing with each release, so you need to regularly make changes to match new Spark releases

Answer (score 1):

`directJoin()` is only implemented in the Spark Cassandra connector (https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector).

You will need to implement something similar to it using the approach that Alex Ott suggested.

P.S. Alex is one of the authors of the Spark Cassandra connector. Cheers!